# window.open() returns undefined or null on 2nd call

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, popup

I have the follow scenario:

I click a link which:
opens a popup window called 'popup' which loads a pdf inside of it (in IE6).

without closing the popup, i click the link again, which should reopen the pdf inside the popup, but instead a javascript error in thrown:
**member not found**

the javascript function used to open the popup is:

```
function openWindow(url, name, props) {
  var windowRef = window.open(url, name, props);
  if (!windowRef.opener) {
    windowRef.opener = self;
  }
  windowRef.focus(); //error at this line, windowRef must be null
  return windowRef;
}
```

question:
how do i get around this, without opening a new popup window every time?

Comment: Is there a popup blocker stopping it from opening the window? Put alert(windowRef); after window.open, to see if the object is undefined.

Comment: In my case, http://stackoverflow.com/a/43313683/3793078

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is the hack that works that everyone on the internets is using:

```
function openWindow(url, name, props) {
  if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){ //do this only in IE
    var windowRef = window.open("", name, props);
    windowRef.close();
  }
  var windowRef = window.open(url, name, props);
  if (!windowRef.opener) {
    windowRef.opener = self;
  }
  windowRef.focus();
  return windowRef;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try to use global var windowRef outside the function openWindow(). Something like this:

```
var WindowRef = null;

function openWindow(url, name, props) {
  if(WindowRef == null){
    WindowRef = window.open(url, name, props)
  }
  else{
    WindowRef.document.location = url
  }
  if (!WindowRef.opener) {
    WindowRef.opener = self;
  }
  WindowRef.focus();
  return WindowRef;
}
```

Comment: this didnt work, WindowRef.document.location = url part was giving me an access denied error.

Comment: is the url of in the same domain?