# Getting window.opener is undefined after google authorization with oauth In IE 10

Tags: oauth, authorization, window.opener

parent page :
 i have a page with button , when i click on button it opens new window with the URL googleoauth.aspx using (window.open() in java script) .

i registered my googleoauth.aspx page in Google console (to access Google data using API) as a redirect URL

child page (googleoauth.aspx ):
   i have a button to authorize with Google account to access Google documents using API .
   When i click on button it opens Google log in page in the same window , after successful log in it         redirecting to a googleoauth.aspx  page with the token . Here i am passing this token to parent function using javascript (window.opener.settoken(token);) and after i am closing this window (window.close()) .
 this works fine in  chrome and Firefox . but in IE   getting undefined at window.opener .
  same issues like [window.open returns always closed in true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972164/window-open-returns-always-closed-in-true)