# Send a refresh request to another page opened in the browser

Tags: php, javascript, refresh

I have page A that creates a window with the page B.

Page B asks the user some datas, inserts them in the database and then closes itself.
After the insertion, I'm trying to make page A refresh automatically (it can be both from A seeing that B has closed, or by a function triggered by B itself before (or after?) closing)

How can I do that?

Comment: possible through JavaScript `window.onclose`, no? Or you trying to do this through PHP only?

Comment: Well maybe, but how can I address page A in this way? (both php or javascript are ok, editing tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's `window.open()` returns reference to the instance of opened window. You may use it to set up `onunload` event handler, like this:

```
var hWndB = window.open('somepage.php'),
    hWndA = window.self;

hWndB.onunload = function(){ hWndA.location.reload(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onunload` event and `window.opener`. For example.

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function() {
   window.opener.location.reload();
}, false);
```

> Or you could use jquery so you wouldn't have any crossbrowser compatibility problems:

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
   window.opener.location.reload();
});
```

Also there is another event called `onbeforeunload` that you might want to take a look at.

> **EDIT**

For older browser you can use the hack that @CORRUPT has provided in the comments: [window.open() returns undefined or null on 2nd call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960293/window-open-returns-undefined-or-null-on-2nd-call)

Comment: `window.opener` is not reliable in some [***cases***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960293/window-open-returns-undefined-or-null-on-2nd-call).

Comment: Thank you. I've added your link to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Variant "A seeing B closed":

```
//winb is global variable
winb=window.open(blah blah); //Existing: A opens B

window.setTimeout(checkWinB,1000);

function checkWinB() {
  if (winb.closed()) refreshMySelf();
  else window.setTimeout(checkWinB,1000);
}
```

Variant "B kicks A":

```
opener.rerfreshMySelf();
window.close() //Existing: B closes
```

Both variants need the `refreshMySelf()` function to refresh the page. How to do this depends on the page mechanism, but a starting point for a non-AJAX page is

```
function refreshMySelf() {
  location.reload();
}
```