# Javascript, Open a tab, run a script then close it and move onto different tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

So My whole plan is to, have a link which I will then enter, the tab is then opened and then a javascript script is run which will select a drop down, after it has done this then the tab is closed. I will need this because I open around 50 tabs, but the first ones load and then it takes a very long time to load all of them.

For example,

Open a tab: such as stack overflow.com once the page has fully loaded, I need it to run the script "document.getElementsByClassName("blah blah")[0].click();" and then close the tab and move onto the next, which will continue about 50 tabs.

Thanks :)

T

Comment: considered creating extensions?

Comment: You aren't trying to trick click ads are you? If so then you should know they can and will find out those clicks were not legitimate and you'll find it's against their agreements... Just a heads up.

Comment: Nothing is working, at the moment and I am unable to figure it out

Comment: this sounds so nefarious...

Comment: what do you mean by it will select a drop down?

Answer (score 0):

You could create the instances using JavaScript. It'd be analog to this:
[How to refresh another page using javascript without opening the same page in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061451/how-to-refresh-another-page-using-javascript-without-opening-the-same-page-in-a)

Comment: Maybe that will work. I think it's easier and quicker opening 50 tabs, running a code on one closing and doing again