# Is there any way to reload/refresh another URL opened in another browser on some event in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my Web application. I want client page get refreshed automatically whenever changes done on Server. I don't want to set automatic reload option in the browser

I gave it a try with Promise concept but no use

When I click on Submit button from one page then the another page opened in another browser (client URL) should get refreshed as well.

Comment: take a look at the websockets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh another page using javascript without opening the same page in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061451/how-to-refresh-another-page-using-javascript-without-opening-the-same-page-in-a)

Comment: In theory you can use something like SignalR (which uses websockets) to open a connection the the server and listen for any events that get pushed to it.

Comment: If your Web application handle session, shared between multiple openend ULRs in different browser, you can consider using [Server-Sent Events](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp).

If your problem is limited to URLs opened via window.open(), then you can check answer linked by @DTul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accomplished this one using Web Sockets concept. My Application is using Grails framework so by integrating grails web socket plugin I got the result what I had expected.