# Refresh another page after submit in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have opened this two page:

1. Page A
2. Page B

How to refresh `B` after something submitted from `Test Controller`

**A Controller**:

```
$this->load->view('admin/page_a');
```

**page_a view**:

```
<?
echo anchor("admin/test/update_data/".$r->k_id,"<input type='button' value='done'>");
?>
```

**Test Controller**:

```
function test($id){
$proc = array('process' => 'In');
$this->mtest->update($id,$proc);
redirect('admin/A/','refresh');
***Some script to refresh page B***
}
```

**B Controller**:

```
$this->load->view('admin/page_b');
```

**page_b view**:

```
some script
```

Comment: please clear you Question more

Comment: Send the value to database and retrieve in  page B. Finish

Comment: @Abdulla What i intend to ask: I still remaining on this page a and page b, after i click that page A button, the page B could auto refresh itself..

Comment: so use database. A will send data and b will get your inserted data

Comment: upload your model  and controller correctly

Comment: @Abdulla the case alike this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853138/send-a-refresh-request-to-another-page-opened-in-the-browser, but in this case we are usin' codeigniter..

Comment: when you submit through page A and you want user to back in Page B with the input of  page A?? IS it??

Comment: @Abdulla no, i want page B auto refresh after i clicked the trigger 'done button' from page A, consider there's no database relation among page A and page B..

Comment: i think its not possible with CI.

Comment: He asks it in very unclear way. I think he wants kind of dinamically changed data on sertain page. Check [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically) and work around page b to solve your issue. Disclaimer: I really thought you wanted this.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your code then the solution would be:

```
<script>
window.onunload = refreshPageB;
function refreshPageB() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Put this code in PageA